# Using special characters in Wordpress outside of main loop or menus

Tags: wordpress, html, character

I'm working on a bi-lingual site in Wordpress using the get text echo call to write any strings that need to be translated like this:

I've noticed something strange though. Any special characters rendered in the main wordpress loop or in the menus are displaying fine, but if I use any special language characters in the header or footer e.g. "Versión en español" then the special characters are being replaced by the � symbol.

I've also tried dropping the text function and just entering the text with special characters but same problem. Is wordpress escaping/processing the special characters within the main loop and menus that I need to do in the header and footer?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi Danjo, did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hard-coding the characters into your themes files you should convert special characters to HTML entities. For example é should be `&eacute;` in HTML. Otherwise they will indeed often show up as question marks.

You can find a reference for the characters [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm). An online converter for your text can be found [here](http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder).